# Proper way to utilize .loc in python's pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

When trying to change a column of numbers from `object` to `float` dtypes using pandas dataframes, I receive the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Now, the code runs just fine, but what would be the proper and intended way to avoid this warning and still achieve the goal of:

```
df2[col] = df2[col].astype('float')
```

Let it be noted that df2 is a subset of df1 using a condition similar to:

```
df2 = df1[df1[some col] == value]
```

Comment: The warning is issued when `df` is itself a copy of some part of another DataFrame. It is warning that modifying `df` won't affect that other DataFrame. So suggest how to address/avoid the warning (which may not really be necessary) we would need to see how `df` is defined.

Comment: edited now, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `copy` method. Instead of:

```
df2 = df1[df1[some col] == value]
```

Just write:

```
df2 = df1[df1[some col] == value].copy()
```

Initially, `df2` is a slice of `df1` and not a new dataframe. Which is why, when you try to modify it, python raises an error.